# Curious error using the function barplot

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, bar-chart

I have a problem using the barplot function to Print a histogram. Every time I call I get the following error. I have checked the functions, but I do not see any errors. I put the function a data.frame input sample, the error and giving me an example of a result. Is there any other way to make histograms as the image?

It's funny because sometimes the function gives the result but other fails giving the error

function:

```
HIST_EPC_list<-function(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter){
  barplot(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter$Num_EPC, names.arg = DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter$Tag_PHASE, xlab = "Tag_PHASE", ylab = "Num_EPC", main="Histograma Num tags/PHASE:", width=10)
}
```

data.frame example:
DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter

```
 Tag_PHASE Num_EPC
1     123.0       1
2      75.0       1
3      78.0       1
4      81.0       2
5      84.0       1
6      87.0       1
7      90.0       2
8      98.0       1
```

Error:

```
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
Called from: barplot(DF_TAG_RSSI_EPC_counter$Num_EPC, names.arg = DF_TAG_RSSI_EPC_counter$Tag_RSSI, 
    xlab = "Tag_RSSI", ylab = "Num_EPC", main = "Histograma Num tags/RSSI:", 
    width = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using RStudio ?

Comment: yes :) but other times it worked

Comment: A histogram is distinct from a bar plot, which are for continuous and categorical data, respectively. You should sort your categories in your plot if you are trying to make a histogram. Or just use a histogram plotting function. For clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "figure margins too large" comes from the fact you are trying to plot a too large graphics compared to the size of the plot frame.

It can happen for instance in RStudio when the plot zone is small.

You can try these these things:

- Enlarge the plot zone in RStudio
- Use `x11()` command before plotting (it creates a new plot window)
- Use `par(mar=...)` function to reduce the margins in your plot. For example, try `par(mar=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1)` (see `?par`)

Comment: but par(margin =), where it is used? 
Can you give me an example?

Comment: the problem is that use that function within another function, my intention is to print the histogram on a html file, using the library R2HTML

Comment: I think you should not have this error if you are plotting in a html file (as when you use `pdf`, `png`... functions to plot in files. This would be weird if you still have this error when plotting in a html file.

Comment: Well now I have other errors but that may be because I use a list of data.frames, the error is: "Error in barplot.default (DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter $ Num_EPC, names.arg = DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter $ Tag_PHASE,: 
   'height' must be a vector or a matrix "

Comment: You should ask another question for other errors in your script. This one is not linked to the first one. Anyway, is your plot problem solved ?

Comment: yes :) If the problem is solved, however, I think I'll have to try ggplot2, it seems more stable than barplot